# How can I display the actual price of a purchase that will be made in credits?

Tags: facebook, api, credits

When I purchase items for a Zynga game, you can see the price in local currency.  What Facebook APIs can be used to determine the price?  Can I get the price of credits in either local currency or US dollars?  Example below.

[image: Price in local currency for items bought with Facebook credits]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 credits = 1 USD

Use an external service for getting current exchange rates for other currencies.

I have used [the free XML file from the European Central Bank](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) in the past, but that's based on the Euro (and up to 1 day old). There's probably lots of other sources available online.

You could just google "[13 USD in GBP](https://www.google.com/search?q=13+USD+in+GBP)" and fetch the result from there.

Comment: That's what I was heading towards, so good to have it confirmed.  I guess you just ignore that the user can get bulk discounts on FB credits?